Is 取れる related to 取られる?
取る means "to take (something)", while 取れる means:

Verb (1-dan)

to come off; to be removed
to disappear (of pain, a fever, etc.)
to be caught; to be harvested
to be interpreted (as); to be taken (as)
to be attained (of balance, etc.)
to be obtainable
potential form of 取る


If I squint my eyes, all of these meanings (except for the last one) seem very much related to a central notion of "being taken", which I expected to be 取られる (passive form of 取る).
Question: Etymologically, is 取れる just a shortened version of 取られる (maybe shortened because it's so commonly used)? If not, what is the difference between 取れる and 取られる, and why would one use one over the other?

取れる is NOT shortened version of 取られる. Japanese has many intransitive - transitive verb pairs, and [取れる, 取る] is one of them. Other examples: [付く, 付ける], [始まる, 始める], [終わる, 終える], [変わる, 変える], [返る, 返す], [戻る, 戻す], [落ちる, 落とす], [降りる, 降ろす], [煮える, 煮る]. See also here.

Probably to distinguish that it's different and the fact that られる form has emphasis on the fact that it was done by someone, rather than it just being taken. This also reminds me of す、らす and らせる (like 減す、減らす and 減らせる) but I have no qualifications to answer this question.

Arfrever is right, I made the same mistake thinking that the らす forms were like らせる

I think 取れる as 自発動詞 is older.

取れる and 取る are a intransitive/transitive pair. 取れる and 取られる are very different to me even if they may sometimes translate to the same English phrase.

取れる is an intransitive verb, and sounds like something is detached spontaneously.
取られる is the passive form of 取る, and it sounds like you're negatively affected.

For example, シャツのボタンが取れた sounds like "the button on the shirt came off (naturally)", while シャツのボタンが取られた sounds like "the button on the shirt was taken off
/ stolen by someone."
Confusingly, 取れる happens to work as the potential form of 取る as well (e.g., 点が取れた usually means "was able to get a score" rather than "the dot came off"). The definition "to be interpreted" is probably based on this (e.g., そう取れる means "you can interpret it that way").
